# Regarding Hosting Static website in Digital ocean spaces

Tags: nginx, lamp, web

I need to host my static website in Digital ocean space. I am looking for something similar that we do in AWS S3 static website hosting in the Digital ocean. Is the feature is available in DO? Looking for some DO experts to render their hands on this.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time DO does not offer static site hosting in "Spaces"; you could set-up a small Droplet (with a reverse proxy, using Nginx or other software) or use "Cloudflare" to act as a middleman in this setup and get things working.

P.S.: This is planned feature, You can up vote at https://ideas.digitalocean.com/ideas/DO-I-318